# MS chart control + XValue member as Time in AM PM format

Tags: mschart

I have a result set from DB which has two columns - 1. Time in AM / PM starting from 1 - 12 AM and then again 1 - 12 PM and 2. some count.

I am displaying a line chart on my page and binding XValueMembers = my time column (which has time in AM / PM) and YValueMembers - count.

The problem is that chart control automatically groups value so on X axis so, I am able to see only values - 1 to 12. Actually result set has each number from 1 - 12 repeated twice because of AM / PM format.

How can I show all values from 1 - 12 AM and 1 - 12 PM on X axis without any grouping.

Answer (score 0):

If your results from the database are integers, I recommend that you create `DateTime` objects.

Than you can use them as your X axis values and format the axis label. For instance:

```
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(2013, 01, 01);
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(2013, 01, 02);
DateTime dateTime3 = new DateTime(2013, 01, 03);

DateTime[] xValues = new DateTime[3] { dateTime1, dateTime2, dateTime3 };
int[] yValues = new int[3] { 0, 1, 2 };

chart.Series[0] = new Series();
chart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMMM dd, yyyy - hh:mm tt";
```

Notice that in this case `tt` represents the AM/PM designator.

You can find other custom date and time string formats [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).